# If condition for date correction VBA

Tags: excel, vba

i found the issue about the date formating and i built an If condition so i can change the ones that don't.

```
With ActiveSheet
        Dim arr As Variant: arr = .UsedRange.Value
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 
            arr(i, 4) = arr(i, 4) 
           If IsNumeric(arr(i, 5)) = True Then
           'MsgBox "The value in A1 is numeric"
           Else
           arr(i, 5) = "=DATEVALUE(MID(RC[-7],1,10))"
           'MsgBox "The value in A1 is not numeric"
        End If

        Next i

        .UsedRange.Value = arr
        .Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
        .Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
    End With
```

I recorded this macro so i could see how to change the value to number:

```
arr(i, 5) = "=DATEVALUE(MID(RC[-7],1,10))"
```

So when it reaches the Range("E:E") it will change into the format i want.

If you can help me to adapt the macro recorded into my If-Then-Else it will be appreciated.

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=DATEVALUE(MID(RC[-7],1,10))"
```

The column i want to change is E

Whole Code:

```
Option Explicit
Sub para_Importar_()

    Dim mPath As Variant 'nunca dejes implicitos los variant
    mPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Archivos de texto (*.txt),*.txt)")
    If VarType(mPath) = vbBoolean Then Exit Sub
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    mPath = Left(mPath, InStrRev(mPath, "\"))

    Dim iFile As String 'ya no se utilizan los símbolos para los tipos de variables
    iFile = Dir(mPath & "*.txt")

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Sheets(1)
Do Until iFile = ""
  ws.Parent.Worksheets.Add after:=ws.Parent.Worksheets(ws.Parent.Worksheets.Count)
  ActiveSheet.Name = iFile

  With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & _
    mPath & iFile, Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1"))
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True: .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = True: .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False: .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileDecimalSeparator = ".": .TextFileThousandsSeparator = ","
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
  End With

  Dim objRange1 As Range

    'Set up the ranges
  Set objRange1 = Range("A1:A1048576")

    'Do the first parse
    objRange1.TextToColumns _
     Destination:=Range("A1"), _
      DataType:=xlDelimited, _
      Tab:=False, _
      Semicolon:=False, _
      Comma:=False, _
      Space:=False, _
      other:=True, _
      OtherChar:="|"

  With Range("A1").CurrentRegion
.Value = Evaluate("IF(ROW( " & .Address & "),CLEAN(TRIM(" & .Address & ")))")
End With

With ActiveSheet
        Dim arr As Variant: arr = .UsedRange.Value
        Dim i As Long
        For i = 2 To UBound(arr) 'empezamos por la fila 2 ya que supongo que la fila 1 tiene encabezados
            arr(i, 4) = arr(i, 4) * 1 'con esto multiplicas el valor de la celda por 1 y se convierte en valor. Dará fallo si alguna celda es texto de verdad.
          'If IsNumeric(arr(i, 5)) Then
           'MsgBox "The value in A1 is numeric"
           'Else
           'MsgBox "The value in A1 is not numeric"
           'Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<--- Update
    End If

       Next i

        .UsedRange.Value = arr
        .Range("D:D").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
        .Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"   'change to any date-based number format you prefer the cells to display
    End With

  With ActiveSheet.Range("a1", ActiveSheet.[a3].CurrentRegion)
    .Cells(2, 1).Select: ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
    .RowHeight = 14: .Font.Size = 8: .Columns.AutoFit
  End With
  iFile = Dir
Loop

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just loop through the column you care about instead of every value in `UsedRange`?

Comment: @urdearboy how can i accomplish that ?

Comment: @urdearboy i uploaded my code because i've trying to adapt the piece of code u gave me but i don't have any success

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop through every cell on your sheet. Just loop through your target column (`Column E`) and perform the negative test (`Not IsNumeric`)

---

```
Sub Date_Fixer()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") '<--- Update
Dim lr As Long, iCell as Range, i as Range

lr = ws.Range("E" & ws.Rows.Count).Row
Set iCell = ws.Range("E2:E" & lr)                 '<--- Assumes data starts on second row

For Each i In iCell
    If Not IsNumeric(i) Then
        i = Mid(i, 1, 10)
    End If
Next i

ws.Range("E:E").NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

End Sub
```

Comment: I have a doubt in the update, my macro loops through files inside a folder and the line where ws is declared, how can i change that ? Because i want to implement it to the macro i use above.

Comment: The new book needs to happen BETWEEN your two loops

Comment: Yeah, it already does that, i think i explained myself wrong, sorry. I should place the piece of code you wrote inside the for or where ? @urdearboy